# show region with different color

Tags: ios, maps, mkmapview, mapkit, highlight

I have an app where I am showing map where I will be showing the driver area allocated to him.

Client want this area will be highlighted with some color.

Sample can be as below.

[image]

Any idea how this can be done?

What I was planning to do is having images for different regions and show image for respective area.

However I just wanted to check if this can be done using MapKit that we already have, I don't want to go with images.

More info on this would be appreciated.

Comment: check out this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial

Comment: use kml and kml parsing.. It might help.

Comment: @pawan : Check my answer.. I think that is easiest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't thought this would be so easy...

Below link will do the trick I was looking for...

http://www.shawngrimes.me/2011/04/adding-polygon-map-overlays/

Comment: @pawan : yeah, its really nice... only more work is taking points to get perfect shape... for one shape there can be 100 points on map :(

Answer (score 0):

Something you may want to try for performance reasons is to use [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) to parse the source data (KML, SHP, etc.) and render out raster tiles, possibly with alpha transparency so that they can be used as a true overlay. Then, you could use those tiles in MapKit or something like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk).

Comment: TileMill is free and open source, the tiles are simple files, and you can host them yourself if you don't want to pay Mapbox. Check out either flat file serving after export with `mbutil` or something like Tilestache.

Answer (score -1):

you can see HTML "map" tag with "area":
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp